# Fitting driven Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got some datapoints of a turning disc. It is supposed to obby the following differential equation:
$I\ddot{\theta}+\gamma\dot{\theta}+k\theta=\tau$,

So it should have the form of a driven harmonic oscillator.
Now my question is how do I get to know the angle at which it will be at equilibrium? I know $I,k$ and $\gamma$. Even numerically would be a good solution.

The data is a set of (t,y) points which clearly resemble the evolution of a driven, damped harmonic oscillator.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a data set $(t,y)$ instead of $(t,\theta)$ since the differential equation is with $\theta$ ?

Comment: Yes, $y$ is identical to $\theta$, sorry about that

Comment: @Tino Kerremans :  A method for computing the coefficients of the equation of damped sinusoidal equation is given pages 66-67 of the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-intégrales . But, since you already know some of the coefficients, the method can be simplified a lot. If you post on the forum an example of your data I could test my available computer program in this particular case. If the test is OK, I will rewrite the method after simplification and post it on the forum.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of the equilibrium point, its time-derivatives must vanish (the equilibrium point doesn't change with time), so $\ddot{\theta}_\mbox{eq} = \dot{\theta}_\mbox{eq} = 0$ and the differential equation then tells you that $\theta_\mbox{eq} = \tau/\kappa$.

Added after more comment exchanges:

Since you have $(t,\theta)$ points, you can estimate $(t,\dot{\theta)}$ and $(t,\ddot{\theta)}$ by using [numerical methods to evaluate derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) and then do a linear regression on the data to estimate $\tau$.

Beware of accumulated errors if you follow this path. I'd strongly recommend reading up on numerical methods. One excellent resource is [this](http://www.nr.com).

Alternatively, you can solve the differential equation analytically and fit the data to obtain both $\tau$ and $\theta_{\mbox{eq}}$. Now, this can be very simple or very complicated, depending on the nature of your driving force and on the values of the known parameters. I'll look only at the simplest case:

- Constant driving force

If $\tau$ is constant, then the general solution of the differential equation is

$$\theta(t) = \frac{\tau}{\kappa} + \mbox{general solution of }\{I\,\ddot{\theta} + \gamma\,\dot{\theta} + \kappa\,\theta = 0\}$$

Since the homogeneous equation is such that its solution $\theta(t)$ satisfies

$$\lim_{t\,\rightarrow\,\infty} \theta(t) = 0$$

then all you need to do to estimate $\theta_{\mbox{eq}}$ is to look at the last data point in chronological order (assuming you have data for a long enough length of time that your system has reached its equilibrium state). From that value of $\theta$ you can then estimate $\theta_{\mbox{eq}}$ and $\tau$:

$$\theta_{\mbox{eq}} = \mbox{last }\theta$$
$$\tau = \kappa\,\theta_{\mbox{eq}}$$

If your driving force is not constant, then you may want to look at [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscdr.html#c2) page for some details on how the solution depends on the parameters, in the case of an under-damped oscillator driven by a sinusoidal external force (that's the next simplest case). Be aware of the fact that your $\gamma$ is not the same as that page's $\gamma$. Theirs is yours divided by $2I$.

Comment: Ok, but I know neither $\theta_{eq}$ or $\tau$

Comment: If you have data points on the angles, their speeds, and accelerations, at various points in time, then you can use the differential equation and the known values of the parameters to numerically estimate $\tau$. A linear regression would be called for.

Comment: Hm, I only have the different angles at different times, not the speed or accelerations. Although I do have the general solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve++A*x%28t%29%27%27%2BB*x%28t%29%27%2BC*x%28t%29%3DD

Answer (score 0):

If the system is at rest and in equilibrium, then $\ddot\theta=0=\dot\theta$ so $\theta=\frac{\tau}{k}$

Comment: Ok, but I know neither $\theta_{eq}$ or $\tau$

Comment: I suppose that Timo Kerremans knows very well that $\theta=\frac{\tau}{k}$. That is probably not the expected answer to his question. He says that $I, k, \gamma$ are known, but not $\tau$. He also have a data set $(t,y)$. I suppose that he want to have the answer derived from the data set. This is a numerical regression problem. If I am wrong, I ask  Timo Kerremans to correct me.

Comment: Sounds like you need to find the general solution of the differential equation and use your data points to estimate the values of the arbitrary constants and $\tau$

Comment: Yes, I do have the general solution of the differential equation, got it from Mathematica. What you are saying might be a good way to begin with. Thank you :)